# Magento 2 Shpping Address Summary section State name did not translate

Tags: magento2, translate, magento-checkout

I want to create my site on Arabic Language but on Shipping Address page State name did not translate I also enter word into i18n csv file but it doesn't work for me.
you can get references using the below image.

[image]

I also Tried below way but it does not work for me.
/var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

```
<if args="visible()">
<text args="address().prefix"></text> <text args="address().firstname"></text> <text args="address().middlename"></text>
<text args="address().lastname"></text> <text args="address().suffix"></text><br/>
<text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"></text><br/>
<translate args="address().city" />, 
<translate args="address().region" /> <text args="address().postcode"></text><br/>
<text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"></text><br/>
<a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

<each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
    <text args="$parent.getCustomAttributeLabel(element)"></text>
    <br/>
</each>
```

Anything other solution is available ?

Comment: use "__()" this to translate state name and let me know if any issue.

Comment: How Can I use in html file ?